# ionic $resource compatibility with old api

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on an ionic project that uses few REST services (mostly get)
The app works fine on browser emulator and android devices with android versions higher then 4.2.
But app do not work on devices with older api.!
Is because of $resource usage instead of $http ?

https://github.com/medhoover/celialib

This is my controllers.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.directive('hideTabs', function($rootScope) {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function($scope, $el) {
          $rootScope.hideTabs = 'tabs-item-hide';
          $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
              $rootScope.hideTabs = '';
          });
      }
  };
})

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope,$ionicScrollDelegate, Produit) {
  $scope.produits = Produit.query();
  $scope.scrollTop = function() {
    $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();
  };

})

.controller('RecettesCtrl', function($scope, $ionicScrollDelegate, Recette) {
  $scope.scrollTop = function() {
    $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();
  };
  $scope.limiter = 8;
  $scope.recettes = Recette.query();

  $scope.increaseLimiter = function() {
       $scope.limiter += 8;

       // Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
       $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');

  };
})

.controller('RecetteDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, recette) {

  $scope.recette = recette
})

.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    enableFriends: true
  };
});
```

And my services.js

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Recette', function($resource){
      return $resource('http://bonprixtunisie.com/celialib/web/recettes/:id',{id: '@id'}, {
                          'query': { method:'GET', isArray:true, responseType:'json' },
                           'get': { method:'GET', isArray:false, responseType:'json' }
                        });
    })

.factory('Produit', function($resource){
      return $resource('http://bonprixtunisie.com/celialib/web/produits/',{}, {
                          'query': { method:'GET', isArray:true, responseType:'json'}
        });
    });
```

Comment: so you said it works fine...so what are you asking?

Comment: It works fine on androids devices with api higher then api19,
I just want to know why it is not running on older api's which are supported by ionic framework.

Comment: so ionic apps runs in the device web engine, on android the web engines are outdated and fragmented. That may be the reason it does not work. I would try doing a build with the crosswalk engine. Then you will have consistent performance across all android devices. https://crosswalk-project.org/

Comment: Thank's Jess if u wanna add your comment as an answer , i will rate it

Comment: thanks, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so ionic apps runs in the device web engine, on android the web engines are outdated and fragmented. That may be the reason it does not work. I would try doing a build with the crosswalk engine. Then you will have consistent performance across all android devices. https://crosswalk-project.org/